# How to style a live RSS feed using XSL

Tags: jquery, xml, xslt, rss

I am trying to re-use an existing RSS feed on my website. What I would like to do is take that existing feed and parse it using jquery:

```
jQuery.getFeed({
   url: 'rss.xml',
   success: function(feed) {
      alert(feed.title);
   }
});
```

I would then like to style that RSS feed using an XSL file. How do I do that when I don't have an XML file to place the XSL stylesheet link in?

Thanks!

Comment: loop through the items in `feed` object and parse them to html. Style the html

Comment: I need to use XSLT to style the feed